# How to prevent VLC from automatically resizing its window according to viewed content resolution?

Tags: vlc-media-player

In a case of mine a very high (compared to the video stream) resolution graphical frame (saying "access denied" (when my IP changes)) can appear instead of a video stream, which makes VLC window to resize, getting bigger than my screen is. This annoys me. Can I set up VLC to never resize its window when I don't do it myself and resize content instead?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

It is really tricky to find the checkbox that needs to be **un-checked**, so you could go edit the rc file (but don't use notepad.exe to do so, as the file will not be formatted).

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\VLC

--- vlcrc.default       2011-12-16 11:46:51.000000000 -0800
+++ vlcrc.noresize      2010-12-05 20:00:26.000000000 -0800
@@ -1088,7 +1088,7 @@
 #qt-maximized=101

 # Resize interface to the native video size (boolean)
-#qt-video-autoresize=1
+qt-video-autoresize=0
```

Here is where you find the option in the interface.

[image: VLC disable resize]

Comment: PS, it was an extreme PITA to find that the first time I was looking for it.  I actually dug into the vlc source before I figured out where they hid that stupid checkbox.

Comment: You also have to set VLC to USE the QT interface.

Comment: +1. Went to the HUGE trouble of actually logging into the site to upvote. That's huge for me bro. lol thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Note that this can also be achieved temporarily with the --no-qt-video-autoresize command line flag

Comment: requires closing and opening before the new behavior takes effect.

Comment: Could you highlight which menu to click and setting to modify?

Comment: @jberger there is a yellow highlight on the checkbox in the picture.  You do need to be in the 'all settings' version of preferences, and In the 'Interfaces -> Main -> Qt' section.

Comment: @Zoredache the yellow highlight blended in with f.lux going orange late at night.  (Personal note to self: don't depend on highlights; use boxes and arrows)

Answer (score 131):

Select *Tools ⇨ Preferences ⇨ Interface* then uncheck the box *Resize interface to video size*.
Finally, restart VLC.

[image]

Comment: This answer is more up to date. The other (accepted) answer seems to apply to older VLC versions prior 2.xx.

Comment: make sure to restart VLC (as stated above). it really is necessary!

Comment: The older answer works if you have the "Show All" or whatever it's called enabled, but this is definitely the quickest way to the solution, nowadays.

Comment: This answer actually highlights which checkbox to modify.

Comment: When I started a video VLC was always maximized. The box was checked by default. So I did: *uncheck box > restart VLC > check box again > restart VLC*. Now whenever I start a video the window resizes to the video original size which is what I wanted. This is in Ubuntu, for some reason the correct behavior wasn't being applied even though the box was selected by default upon installation of VLC.

Comment: This works well 
If you would like to use Custom Skins, uncheck it after switching to native style. Do a restart and switch back to Custom Skin ;)

Answer (score 18):

First choose the window size you like the VLC window to be.

Then hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and close the window with the X icon.

When you reopen VLC, it should open the window in the same size you closed it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me and is exactly what I needed.

Comment: +1 That checkbox in settings doesn't make sens, but this method made the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [VLC documentation](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help), I found:

```
--sout-transcode-maxwidth=<integer>
  Maximum output video width.

--sout-transcode-maxheight=<integer>
  Maximum output video height.
```

However, running VLC from the command line requires a lot of setup (including settings from the standard module and the transcode module), so you may want to take a look at their [Examples](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples).

I'm going to install VLC on this computer and look into setting max sizes through the GUI. I'll report back if I find anything.

Comment: I am almost certain that he doesn't want to transcode anything, he just wants the interface to stop resizing.

Comment: Way to go, @zoredache! I voted for you.

Answer (score 1):

I unchecked Lock Aspect Ratio and Resize interface to the native video size.
This can be found under Interface > Main interfaces > macosx or qt
Make sure to click Show All to see these preferences.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> when you open a video.

You can then resize it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Select Tools ⇨ Preferences ⇨ Interface then **uncheck** the box Resize interface to video size and the box Integrate video in interface, restart.

Start movie now, if you notice there should be 2 windows the main and the video window in 2 separate windows now.

Go back Select Tools ⇨ Preferences ⇨ Interface then **check** Integrate video in interface 
Finally, restart VLC.

The video windows return normal to its default inside the main window now the movie stay in the location you want, resize as you like, close the movie open and notice stays in the size you have choosen.

I don't know how it this but after trying that's how it works for me.

Other option I have found is:

[image]