# Making VLC start with a pre-set size and position

Tags: vlc-media-player

I haven't found that in the settings, so I'm hoping for a hacky way to get it working.

When I start VLC, sometimes the window is tiny-tiny and sometimes almost full screen. When the latter occurs, it often gets placed so that the right part of it is outside the screen.

Of course, by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> I can make it to full-screen but I'm a bit annoyed because I feel that the computer gets to decide and I'm not in full control.

Is there a way (in the settings that I've missed or by editing some file or registry) to always start VLC at a certain position and with a certain width and/or height?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent VLC from automatically resizing its window according to viewed content resolution?](http://superuser.com/questions/368743/how-to-prevent-vlc-from-automatically-resizing-its-window-according-to-viewed-co)

Comment: See the answer by [wentblackwentback](http://superuser.com/users/128246/wentblackwentback) in the duplicate

Comment: @DavidPostill Sadly, that's not it. I did mention that I went through the settings (although, there are days when one is foggy-minded, so I don't blame anybody for assuming it **might** be it). Setting that flag off starts the player in a minimal window (only controls are visible, no actual video). So the question isn't a duplicate. I'm looking for a fixed size (or at least width and preferably also the position) of the window each time I start up a playback. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, since I use a TV for video watching. The VLC refused to remember its screen, which I defined as No. 2, its size and position. Thus, I thought something had been changed in the later versions, but I was wrong.

Windows can remember exactly where and at what size to start VLC if one holds down the Ctrl key and closes the software's window with the  **X**  button in the right top corner.

There's one condition, however. It does not work if the VLC window has been maximised. Click the middle button, and set size and position before closing VLC.

Answer (score 2):

Tools> Preferences - Simple view> (under "look and feel")> [ ]deselect "resize interfce to video size"> [/] select integrate video in interface> save> manually resize screen to your preference> Media - select quit to lock setting.

Reopen video and it will open to ehatever size you left it at.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the fact that --width and --height don't actually work and haven't since VLC v2.1.0, it looks like this won't be fixed now.

https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/9931

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: It's Videolan's bug tracking system so it'll be around for a while.

There's a report from November 2013 in which someone raises the point that --width and --height don't work. A few additions of reports since then and someone pointing out that the problem is still not resolved in V3.0.0. Finally someone chiming in in December 2017 asking if there's any progress.

At no time was there any participation from Videolan as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can set command line parameters `--width` and `--height`. 
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Video_options

Answer (score -1):

Open VLC.  Go to tools/preferences/interface.
Uncheck "resize interface to video size".  That should fix the problem.

Comment: This answer has already been given, and the OP says that it is not the solution to his problem.